# SQL Server sp_help to pull out just the columns information

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dmv

The SP_HELP procedures produces multiple subsets of data and I would only like to have the columns information from that. Is there a way to maybe write a query using sp_help to just pull out that information.

I need to do this to build a metadata database and maintain it on a weekly basis. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
RV.

Comment: Are you just looking for a list of columns and their associated meta data?

Comment: Yes. Primary information that I need are the column_name, data type, length and nullability. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you want can be found with:

```
select * from sys.columns
```

However, it can be difficult to navigate using just that table. I like to query the schema, tables, and columns views for this.

```
select
    schemas.name as [schema]
    ,tables.name as [table]
    ,columns.*
from sys.schemas
join sys.tables on
    schemas.schema_id = tables.schema_id
join sys.columns on
    tables.object_id = columns.object_id
```

You can get more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SchemaName'
      AND TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```

This should work.